# NGINX + PHP-FPM uses access_log for 404 instead of error_log

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have `nginx 1.4.6` on Ubuntu with `php5-fpm 5.5.9` on Ubuntu.

Nginx's config for the WebSite contains:

```
...
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev-vm.domain.com-access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-vm.domain.com-error.log debug;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/dev-vm.domain.com-error.log error;
...
```

And a Website's PHP-FPM config with:

```
...
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/nginx/dev-vm.domain.com-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
...
```

And `php.ini` with:

```
# cat /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini | grep var/log
error_log = /var/log/nginx/php-error.log
```

A problem is - only `*.php` files will go to the `error` log, but without exactly 404 message:

> 2016/11/15 11:52:03 [error] 47523#0: *39 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 194.*.*.45, server: dev-vm.domain.com, request:
>   "GET /scsdc.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/dev-vm.domain.com.sock:", host:
>   "dev-vm.domain.com"

But images 404 - still going to `access.log` instead of `error.log`:

> 194.***.***.45 - - [15/Nov/2016:11:54:53 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/10/160829_netzeband_183-1.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 18168 "http://dev-vm.domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu
>   Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"

What I missed here?

That's not my first WordPress on NGINX+PHP-FPM setup, and on another host - I have it working pretty well:

```
# cat /var/log/nginx/vhosts/anotherdomain/anotherdomain.co.ua-error.log | grep 404 | wc -l
325596
```

Comment: The error log is to record problems with your server, not that some random user mistyped a URL.

Comment: What kind of entries for 404 error codes are on the server where it works "pretty well"?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `open() "/var/www/vhosts/host/host.co.ua/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/ssh_logo.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory)` - for example. Image's 404 error message.